# Override global variables in Tibco for testing

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

What is the best way to override global variables in Tibco for testing? Whenever I start a tester I would like to override some of the global variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change global Variables in the Tester via the "-p" option in the advanced dialog.
[image: advanced dialog]

The lines in the file should look like this:

```
tibco.clientVar.<GlobalVariableGroup/GlobalVariableName>=<value>
```

e.g.

```
tibco.clientVar.Connection/JMS/Username=user1
```

Please don't forget to put an empty line at the end of the file.

Comment: I found out myself (and updated the answer), but I have another question. Can I use a relative path to the project for that file?

Comment: Can I have a space in the file name? How do I specify a file like `c:\a dir\a file.cfg`?